# RegisterStartupScript on Logout page

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to have a logout page where is displays a messages and then redirects to the login page. This is in ASP.net 2.0.

I have this in my `Page_Load`:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "pageredirect", JavascriptRedirect() );
```

This is my redirect function:

```
private string JavascriptRedirect()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">");
    sb.Append("var x = 5;");
    sb.Append("var y = 1;");
    sb.Append("function startClock(){");
    sb.Append("x = x-y;");
    sb.Append("t=setTimeout(\"startClock()\", 1000);");
    sb.Append("if(x==0){");
    sb.Append("window.location='login.aspx';");
    sb.Append("clearTimeout(t);");
    sb.Append(" }");
    sb.Append(" }");
    sb.Append("startClock();");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

When I test there is no javascript in my resulting logout page. Anyone have an idea on what is happening. Is `Page_Load` to late to register this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way: You don't need Javascript to redirect the browser to a page after a certain amount of time. Just use a plain HTML meta Tag in your `<HEAD>` section.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=login.aspx">
```

The number stands for the time in seconds, the URL for the target.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typeof(Page), try typeof(YOURPAGECLASS) -- with YOURPAGECLASS set the name of your page's classname.  Page_Load is definitely not too late.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is something unusual going on in your execution pipeline?

When I create a new .aspx and paste in the code you're providing in your question, it works as you expect it to (i.e. Javascript is rendered to the client).

Answer (score 0):

I would register it like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "script here", true);
```

The last 'true' tells ASP.NET to render the script tags and CDATA so you don't have to write it all out.

You may also want to place your javascript in a separate include file so that you don't have to recompile if/when you tweak it. If you do that, then in your page load you'd have:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("RedirectInclude", "scripts/redirect.js");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "JavascriptRedirect();", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't undesrtand why it doesn't work, but i can give you a workaround:

declare an asp:literal item in the page. in pageLoad,

yourLiteral.Text = JavascriptRedirecct();